# Unable to read from Excel as 'java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell cannot be cast to java.lang.String' is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

I'm trying to automate a website in which I'm trying to read data from Excel & entering the data one after another in a textbox.

I'm using 'org.apache.poi' version 3.12. However, when I'm trying to enter the data from excel, I get the "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell cannot be cast to java.lang.String" error. On searching for the below error on google, I found that we need to use 'DataFormatter' to format a Cell. Even after using DataFormatter, I'm continuing to see the below error.

The code to read from excel is as below

```
public static ArrayList iterateCells(String sheetName) {
    // Array List to store the excel sheet data
    ArrayList excelData = new ArrayList();
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    try {
        FileInputStream userDetailsFile = new FileInputStream("D:\\userLoginDetails.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(userDetailsFile);

        //Retrieve the first sheet of the workbook.
        //HSSFSheet excelSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int index = wb.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(index);

        // Iterate through the sheet rows and cells.
        // Store the retrieved data in an arrayList
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                df.formatCellValue(cell);
                excelData.add(cell);
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return excelData;
}
```

And my code to enter the values into the webpage is as below.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="AddCardioExerciseForTheDay")
public void AddStrengthExerciseForTheDay() throws Exception {
    engineDriver.landingPageAfterLoggingIn.addExerciseAfterLoggingIn();
    List colData = new ArrayList();
    colData = wte.iterateCells("DataSheet");
    String exerciseType = (String) colData.get(1);

    engineDriver.exercisePage.selectStrengthExercise(exerciseType);
    engineDriver.exercisePage.goToAddFoodPage();
}
```

Could someone point me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!!

**EDIT:** I'm getting the error in the following line

```
String exerciseType = (String) colData.get(1);
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.myfitnesspal.tests.MfpExerciseLoggingTest.AddStrengthExerciseForTheDay(MfpExerciseLoggingTest.java:107)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: What on earth makes you think you can do this `String exerciseType = (String) colData.get(1);`? Has casting random objects to `String` ever worked for you?

Comment: Apache poi has methods for getting different types of data in excel. Use that instead.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and mark the line where the error occurs

Comment: I think most of the confusion arises from the dogged determination to use rawtypes in 2017. Don't. Ever. Use. Rawtypes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getStringCellValue()` on a cell to get its content as a String.

In your case, I think it should be :

```
String exerciseType = colData.get(1).getStringCellValue();
```

See : [apache poi cell documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29)